# Maintain same border-size when empty cell is removed in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got what I want as per the screenshot. However, the borders got attached to one another and got thicker. How do I maintain the border size?

This is actually what I'm planning to make it look like:
[image]

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/xnqh9d70/

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Day</td>
        <td>Sun.</td>
        <td>Mon.</td>
        <td>Tues.</td>
        <td>Wed.</td>
        <td>Thu.</td>
        <td>Fri.</td>
        <td>Sat.</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fare(s)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date(s)</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
    border: 0;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the nicest solution, but what you can do is eliminate one of the two borders completely, only having borders on elements where it is needed then.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
    border: 0;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid black
}

tr {
  border-bottom: none;
}

td {
  border-left: none;
}

tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Day</td>
        <td>Sun.</td>
        <td>Mon.</td>
        <td>Tues.</td>
        <td>Wed.</td>
        <td>Thu.</td>
        <td>Fri.</td>
        <td>Sat.</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fare(s)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date(s)</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The general way for creating borders between cells is by styling the `td` elements, and setting `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table.

I also added a class for your blank cells to remove the border on them.

```css
table {
  empty-cells: hide;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #000000;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.empty-cell {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Sun.</td>
      <td>Mon.</td>
      <td>Tues.</td>
      <td>Wed.</td>
      <td>Thu.</td>
      <td>Fri.</td>
      <td>Sat.</td>
      <td class="empty-cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fare(s)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td class="empty-cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date(s)</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty-cells: hide;` is use to hide border

> The empty-cells property sets whether or not to display borders on
>   empty cells in a table. [Reference Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp)

you can apply css to `td:empty` for hide empty `td`

and for `border-collapse: separate;` case you need to add manually border-right to last td

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #000000;
  empty-cells: hide;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:empty {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Sun.</td>
      <td>Mon.</td>
      <td>Tues.</td>
      <td>Wed.</td>
      <td>Thu.</td>
      <td>Fri.</td>
      <td>Sat.</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fare(s)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date(s)</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```